Can't launch a cron job at the configured time
I'm running a docker container with Debian. Crontab is configured as follows:
#!/bin/sh

SHELL=/bin/sh

16 16 * * * /bin/sh /app/script.sh

The cron job is not running in this case, but running as expected if */1 * * * * or */10 * * * *, for example.
Solutions from the search suggest adjusting a proper timezone. So timezone has been changed from initial UTC to my actual zone with
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

date command displays:
Sun Sep  8 16:14:44 +05 2024

, which is my actual timezone time now.
After changing the server timezone cron service has been restarted with:
service cron restart

All actions and commands within the container via its exec. I didn't wait 24 hours to figure out if it starts running at a different time. Just tried to set up a time in the nearest future.
Additionally:
diff -s /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/`cat /etc/timezone` 
Files /etc/localtime and /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Almaty are identical.

And it seems that cron itself is up and running 'cause I can get its PID with pgrep cron.
But still, the task is not executed at the exact time specified. Can you please tell me why that is and how to make cron do the task at the intended time?
Actually, I don't have any logs and failed to make them appear, probably 'cause it's docker's Debian.

Um, your crontab says 16 16 …, and you’re posting at 16:14 to say it didn’t work?   What happened two minutes later?

A lot of useful contab debugging info available on the StackOverflow cron.info page. Is such documentation possible/available here on U&L as well?

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' nothing happened, no script execution

@shellter i didn't see it, looks useful, thank you!

Well, it's fixed.
Everything is ok with Cron!
Mea culpa. I lost focus somewhere while debugging and playing around with a number of different solutions. And I deleted a piece of data influenced by my app.
So Cron and the script worked good as intended. I just couldn't see it.
Many thanks to shellter (and StackOverflow, of course), cause their link provided consistent information helped me out.
First, I echoed logs(!) to a file.
Second, came to realize that cron and sh-script work perfect.
Third, my app works good as well, but just silently because of the data removed.
No additional adjustments needed for Cron.
16 16 * * * works as well.
Appreciate your assistance, guys!

Ah, great. Glad you found it. I closed the question as non reproducible since it seems very specific to your setup, but thank you for taking the time to post the answer!
